# COMException in Outlook Online (non-cached) Mode only

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

The example code shown below illustrates the issue I'm having, namely when I start Outlook in Online mode I cannot get most of the properties of the mail item passed to the OutboxItems_ItemAdd handler.  The error returned is:

```
Attachments = {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004010F
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime...
```

I do NOT get this error when attempting to retrieve the properties of the mail item in the SentItems_ItemAdd handler.  Also, it is important to note that everything works perfectly when in Outlook cached mode; the issue in the Outbox handler is only when Outlook starts in Online mode.  Is this a bug, or am I just doing something wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace OnlineErrorTest{
public partial class ThisAddIn{

    Outlook.Folder sentFolder;
    Outlook.Folder outboxFolder;
    Outlook.Items sentItems;
    Outlook.Items outboxItems;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        sentFolder = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) as Outlook.Folder;
        outboxFolder = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox) as Outlook.Folder;
        sentItems = sentFolder.Items;
        outboxItems = outboxFolder.Items;
        sentItems.ItemAdd += SentItems_ItemAdd;
        outboxItems.ItemAdd += OutboxItems_ItemAdd;
    }

    private void OutboxItems_ItemAdd(object Item) {
        Outlook.MailItem mi = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
        Outlook.Recipients r = mi.Recipients; //CAUSES EXCEPTION //System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004010F
    }

    private void SentItems_ItemAdd(object Item) {
        Outlook.MailItem mi = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
        Outlook.Recipients r = mi.Recipients; //WORKS FINE
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
   }


    private void InternalStartup(){
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The error code is MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND. Which lien raises the excepiton?

Comment: Only in Online mode=> Outlook.Recipients r = mi.Recipients; //CAUSES EXCEPTION //System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004010F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code is `MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`, which means the item no longer exists - this is hardly surprising: by the time your code gets to it, Exchange Server most likely already sent the message and moved it to the Sent Items folder.

You should never touch the messages being submitted - even if you succeed in doing so, touching an item with OOM aborts the submission process. Use `Application.ItemSend` event instead - it is your last chance to access the item before it is handed over to the spooler and sent.

Comment: Yes I'm using ItemSend also, but the problem is I need to measure the signing and encryption process which means I don't seem to have any choice other than the Outbox add event.  It's odd that Microsoft provides an event handler but doesn't document the fact it only works in cached mode

Comment: I would not expect it to work in neither cached nor online mode. The event handler is there for all folders, it is what you do there that matters.

Comment: I've got about 10K users and it seemed to be working fine for years in cached mode, although now that you mention it every once in a while I do hear about a user with an email suck in the outbox; rare, but I still hear about it.  I think I'm gonna take your suggestion, err on the side of caution, and stop touching the OOM in the outbox handler

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko, may I know how did you find out that the error code is `MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`?

Comment: 0x8004010F - see above